# How to filter dictionary of datatime objects based on weeks

Tags: python, dictionary

So, I've pulled data from fitbit API and got dictionary in following format:

```
weightData = {'January': {datetime.date(2018, 1, 1): {'weight': 0, 'fat': 0}, datetime.date(2018, 1, 2): {'weight': 0, 'fat': 0}
```

Now I want to calculate averages for every week. I searched google and found datetime.isocalendar() method. It works great but I can't figure out how to loop through dict. This is my attempt:

```
for i in range (1, 30):
for month in data:
    for date in data[month]:
        if date.isocalendar()[1] == i:
            tmpWeight += data[month][date]["weight"]
            tmpFat += data[month][date]["fat"]
            counter += 1
        elif date.isocalendar()[1] > i:
            continue
avgWeight.append(tmpWeight/counter)
avgFat.append(tmpFat/counter)
tmpWeight = 0
tmpFat = 0
counter = 0
```

But I'm getting "ZeroDivisionError: division by zero". I assume it happens when date.isocalendar()[1] != i and it tries to divide some values by "counter" which has value of 0.

Can someone point me my mistake?

Comment: `I can't figure out how to loop through dict` you can do `weightData.items` and loop through dictionary. It will yield key and value pair each time

Comment: Maybe I described it incorrectly. I know how to loop through dict, but can't find a way to actually get the weight value for dates within the same week, and then calculate the average and append it to a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can solve your problem as followed:

```
import datetime

data = {
    'January': {
        datetime.date(2018, 1, 1): {'weight': 1, 'fat': 30}, 
        datetime.date(2018, 1, 2): {'weight': 15, 'fat': 300}
    }
}

result = dict()

for month in data.keys():
    for date in data[month].keys():

        week_number  = date.isocalendar()[1]

        if week_number not in result.keys():
            result[week_number] = {
                "weight": 0,
                "fat": 0,
                "counter": 0
            }                

        result[week_number]["weight"] += data[month][date]["weight"]
        result[week_number]["fat"] += data[month][date]["fat"]
        result[week_number]["counter"] += 1

for week_number in result.keys():  
    result[week_number] = {
        "weight": result[week_number]["weight"] / result[week_number]["counter"],
        "fat": result[week_number]["fat"] / result[week_number]["counter"]
    }

print(result)
```

It gives you:

```
{1: {'weight': 8.0, 'fat': 165.0}}
```

The code you proposed was highly inefficient for the following reasons:

- a loop from 1 to 30 which was useless
- temp values not necessary
- average values not necessary
- you didn't check that counter was != 0 before dividing in a unecessary complex algorithm

Comment: Oh boy, I made a mistake. I will correct, thanks @SergeBallesta

Comment: I didn't want to use defaultdict because it was a bit more complicated to understand, and I tried to keep it easy ;) However, I fuilly agree! @smela, if it's fine with you please accept the response. That way we know we have answered your question